# Isotope plugin causes whitespace after footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope plugin [here](http://lcc-web.ru/art/) in order to lay out these tiles nicely, but apparently it causes a whitespace of 1px after my footer, and I don't know how to fix that.

I came to this, since removing div.content (inside of div.wrapper) removes the whitespace, so it has to do something with the plugin I'm using.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Hard to tell without having a full look at the rendered HTML and CSS. It may not be the plugin at all. Can you post a link to the actual site or a reduced sample so we can help you out?

Comment: @Danny Yeah, you can have a look @ my [github repo](https://github.com/R-Oscar/Art)

Comment: What browser is this being tested on? I cannot replicate the 1px error bug. Also, can you indicate in a screenshot what exactly the error is about?

Comment: @DannyH [Here](http://i.imgur.com/V0v0oko.png).
Switched the background to red for the illustrative purpose. I'm using latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I have pulled your repo, tested this on all browsers and the issue you are mentioning cannot be replicated. Are you sure the entirety of your code is up in Git?

Comment: @DannyH That seems kind of strange, as I've just pulled the repo as well and got the same white line as before...